# F# query expression nested lists

Tags: f#

I'm trying to query a list of events each containg a list of attendees.
I'm using a query expression on an EF db context.
I've managed to do it like this:

```
 let events =
     query {
         for event in db.Events do             
         leftOuterJoin ea in db.EventAttendances 
           on (event.Id = ea.EventId) into result

         for ea in result do
         select ({|Id = event.Id
                   Description = event.Description
                   DateTime = event.DateTime
                 |}, {| FirstName = ea.Member.FirstName
                        LastName = ea.Member.LastName
                        IsAttending = ea.IsAttending |})
     }
     |> Seq.toList
     |> List.groupBy (fun (e, _) -> e)
     |> List.map (fun (e, attendees) ->
         { Id = e.Id
           Description = e.Description
           DateTime = e.DateTime
           Attendees = attendees
                       |> Seq.map(fun (_, a) ->
                           { FirstName = a.FirstName
                             LastName = a.LastName
                             IsAttending = ea.IsAttending })
                       |> Seq.toList

            } )
```

I'm used to doing this with EF, so the whole `groupBy` thing seems a little cumbersome to me.
Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions shows a `groupBy` expression that can be used in queries, as well as several variants. I haven't used them before so I can't give you a complete answer, but that might be enough to get you started.

Comment: Please don't just ask for opinion, or vague notions such as "better" or "smarter" ways to do something. Be specific about what you want and what is lacking about the current approach. This will make the question easier to answer, give better answers, and make it easier for others with the same or similar questions to find it. As it is, this is borderline off-topic. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is pretty much exactly what `groupJoin` does.

```
let events =
    query {
        for event in db.Events do
        groupJoin ea in db.EventAttendances on (event.Id = ea.EventId) into result
        select (event, query { for ea in result do
                               select { FirstName = ea.Member.FirstName
                                        LastName = ea.Member.LastName
                                        IsAttending = ea.IsAttending } })
    }
    |> Seq.map (fun (e, attendees) ->
         { Id = e.Id
           Description = e.Description
           DateTime = e.DateTime
           Attendees = attendees |> Seq.toList })
    |> Seq.toList
```